# Adding a command inside \addcontentsline breaks hyperref

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, oldstylenums

here is my problem: by default I use oldstyle numbers in my document, but for the numbers of the headings (in this case the section headings), I would like to use lining numbers.

To do this, I have modified two commands:

`\@seccntformat`, which I define as:

```
\def\@seccntformat#1{{\liningNumbers\csname the#1\endcsname}\ }
```

and `\@sect`, which I define as :

```
\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
    \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth%
        \let\@svsec\@empty%
    \else%
        \refstepcounter{#1}%
        \protected@edef\@svsec{\@seccntformat{#1}\relax}%
    \fi%
    \@tempskipa #5\relax%
    \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@%
        \begingroup%
            #6{%
                \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}%
                \interlinepenalty \@M #8\@@par%
            }%
        \endgroup%
        \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
        \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
            \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth%
            \else%
                \protect{{\protect\liningNumbers\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}}}% Changed line: added "\liningNumbers" to change section numbers
            \fi%
            #7%
        }%
    \else%
    \def\@svsechd{%
        #6{%
            \hskip #3\relax%
            \@svsec #8%
        }%
        \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
        \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
            \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else%
                \protect{{\protect\liningNumbers\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}}}% Changed line: added "\liningNumbers" to change section numbers
            \fi%
            #7%
        }%
    }%
    \fi%
    \@xsect{#5}%
}
```

where only two lines of code have been changed to add a `\liningNumbers` command within a `\addcontentsline` command.

The display is correct and the section number is displayed correctly. I don't redefine the `\thesection` command to include a `\liningNumbers` command because when I refer to a section number in the text, it is preferable that the number be written with oldstyle numbers.

The problem occurs when I use the `hyperref` package. Using `\liningNumbers` inside `\addcontentsline` changes the way `hyperref` names sections in the PDF document. Like this :

[image]

And I have this warning :

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode): removing `\addfontfeatures' on input line XX.
```

Is there a way around this?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec, lipsum, hyperref}
\setmainfont{LibertinusSerif}[Numbers={Proportional, OldStyle}]

\newcommand{\liningNumbers}{\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Lining}}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thechapter{\@Roman\c@chapter}
\renewcommand\thesection{\@arabic\c@section}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\@alph\c@subsection}
\def\@seccntformat#1{{\liningNumbers\csname the#1\endcsname}\ }% Formatting the section number, added : "\liningNumbers"

\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
    \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth%
        \let\@svsec\@empty%
    \else%
        \refstepcounter{#1}%
        \protected@edef\@svsec{\@seccntformat{#1}\relax}%
    \fi%
    \@tempskipa #5\relax%
    \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@%
        \begingroup%
            #6{%
                \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}%
                \interlinepenalty \@M #8\@@par%
            }%
        \endgroup%
        \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
        \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
            \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth%
            \else%
                \protect{{\protect\liningNumbers\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}}}% Changed line: added "\liningNumbers" to change section numbers
            \fi%
            #7%
        }%
    \else%
    \def\@svsechd{%
        #6{%
            \hskip #3\relax%
            \@svsec #8%
        }%
        \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
        \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
            \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else%
                \protect{{\protect\liningNumbers\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}}}% Changed line: added "\liningNumbers" to change section numbers
            \fi%
            #7%
        }%
    }%
    \fi%
    \@xsect{#5}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter one}
    \section{Section I.1}
        \subsection{Subsection I.1.a}
            \lipsum[1-2]
        \subsection{Subsection I.1.b}
            \lipsum[1-2]
    \section{Section I.2}
        \subsection{Subsection I.2.a}
            \lipsum[1-2]
        \subsection{Subsection I.2.b}
            \lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\newcommand{\liningNumbers}{\texorpdfstring{\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Lining}}}{}}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you very much, could you put this as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define your command so that it works in bookmarks and in text with the help of `\texorpdfstring`

```
\newcommand{\liningNumbers}{\texorpdfstring{\addfontfeatures{Numbers={Lining}}}{}}
```

If you are unsure if hyperref is loaded or not you can make sure that `\texorpdfstring` is defined with

```
\providecommand\texorpdfstring[2]{#1}
```